# How to check Bluetooth audio codecs on Android 5.0

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

I have an old Note 3 phone that I use as a music player. I am trying to find out if it supports the aptX Bluetooth codec. I turned on developer mode and all the instructions I can find online say to go to “Audio codec” under the “Developer Options” menu. I go to the “Developer Options” menu but there is no entry for “Audio codec.” On Android 5.0 are the codecs listed in a different place?

If it does not have aptX is that something that can be added?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62737/list-of-supported-a-v-and-image-codecs/212226#212226

Comment: aptX needs to be supported in hardware therefore it can not be added to an Android smartphone. At least for the non-US versions aptX support seems to present in Samsung Galaxy Note 3: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/solved-aptx-support-for-the-note-3-us-european-korean-version-confirmed.2455303/

Comment: @Robert Thanks for that info. Hopefully someone will answer how to look that up. The answer Reddy put as possible dupe doesn't make sense to me. Sometimes I think you have to go in and activate aptX.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have never used ADB. Maybe I can try that. It just seems there should be some way to look up the audio codecs without a third party tool. Maybe not.

Comment: Have you tried [Media Codec Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tyniw.mediacodecinfo.application)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio aptX is a Bluetooth codec. From what I can see the media Codec Info app you have linked only shows audio/video codec available on Android. On my aptX capable tablet it does not show anything regarding aptX.

Comment: @Robert Noted, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to check I found so far is in the **Android Developer Options**.

On some devices there is an entry named "**Bluetooth-Audio-Codec**". If this list contains an entry with "aptX" as shown in the following screen shot it should be sure that the device supports aptX:

[image]

The screen shot is from an Android 9 tablet. Not sure about older Android versions. It may happen that you don't have no "Bluetooth-Audio-Codec" entry in the Developer Options menu, in that case this method does not work for you.

Comment: Don't know if this is universal, but `/system/etc/bt_configstore.conf/` has many properties per platform. Each platform has a property named `a2dpOffloadCapability` whose value is those codecs. In my Oneplus 6, for my SoC/platform, the value is `sbc-aptx-aptxtws-aptxhd-aac-ldac`. They are exactly what listed in that developer option setting too.

Comment: @Firelord I checked all my devices I have access to (4 in total from Sony, Lenovo, Samsung, Google running Android 8-11) and none of them had this directory, just the standard `/system/etc/bluetoth/`. Googling for `bt_configstore.conf` does not get you many results and most of them are related to Chinese Android manufacturer. Therefore this directory does not seem to be universal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And sorry, the full path was `/system/etc/bluetooth/bt_configstore.conf`. OnePlus is also a Chinese OEM so that clears things.

Comment: @Firelord I made a full-text search in `/system/etc/` for `grep -Ri apt` respectively `grep -Ri aptx` but no result :(